# Redirect or Render UI in NestJS

Tags: node.js, nestjs

How can I have a controller in NestJS that redirects to a link but if something goes wrong, renders a UI?

Something like this is always giving me a redirect:

```
@Post()
@Redirect()
public async authenticateUser(
    @Body('email') email: string,
    @Body('password') password: string,
    @Body('challenge') loginChallenge: string,
    @Body('remember') remember: string,
    @Res() res: Response,
) {
    try {
        const redirectUrl = await this.loginService.authenticateUser(
            email,
            password,
            loginChallenge,
            remember,
        );
        return {
            url: redirectUrl,
        };
    } catch (error) {
        return res.render('login', {
            challenge: loginChallenge,
            errorMessage: error && error.message ? error.message : undefined,
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect using Express's `<Express.Response>.redirect("url")` method.

```
@Post() // remove @Redirect decorator from here
public async authenticateUser(
    @Body('email') email: string,
    @Body('password') password: string,
    @Body('challenge') loginChallenge: string,
    @Body('remember') remember: string,
    @Res() res: Response,
) {
    try {
        const redirectUrl = await this.loginService.authenticateUser(
            email,
            password,
            loginChallenge,
            remember,
        );
        return res.redirect(redirectUrl); // use res.redirect instead of @Redirect
    } catch (error) {
        return res.render('login', {
            challenge: loginChallenge,
            errorMessage: error && error.message ? error.message : undefined,
        });
    }
}
```